# Using ReactJS BigCalendar component from NancyFx

Tags: reactjs, bundle, nancy, jsx

We are using `nancyFx` to create our web application. I need to embed the [big calendar](https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar) component in this application. But the problem is, the example on github page is using a lot of `Jsx` files and those files are compiled to a single bundle upon execution. It also uses `node.js` as server side technology and `webpack` for packaging and bundling. Currently, I am unable to find how I can achieve this packaging and bundling from `nancyFx` platform?

I have had a look at Reactjs.NET but it seems to be written with `asp.net mvc` in mind.

Answer (score 0):

React is just the view component. You can use webpack-dev-server for development and then use webpack to build a bundle.js file, which you can upload to your production environment. React is agnostic to the server technology you're using, as long as you provide valid JSON responses to it.

Your webpack configuration should use Babel to transpile the jsx. Take a look at [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter/blob/master/webpack.config.js).

Comment: Salte, I understand what you mean but I want to keep away from `Node.js` for this project. Is transpiling and bundling possible with .net especially with `nancyFx`?

Comment: The repo you just mentioned is also using `npm`